# Silverlight based interactive floor plan

Tags: silverlight, shapefile

Our client is going to have a big screen in a reception area where they will have a browser based view of the laboratory floor plan. The idea is to interactively feed in lab temperatures for each room and have the floor plan change when a significant change in temperature occurs.

Silverlight will be the foundation technology for this, but that's where my experience with this ends. I don't know silverlight very well, but I should be ok with it once I get started.

I have the following two routes so far: 
1. Just draw out the outlines in Silverlight and overlay it with extra shapes to represent elements like air conditioners, etc. 
2. Telerik has a Map control that makes use of ESRI shapefiles, which seemed interesting and they actually have a Hotel sample where you can interact with various rooms, but when I asked them how they generated those shapefiles, they couldn't answer.

Anyone done something similar?

Shapefiles seemed interesting, but when I downloaded MapWindow and Quantum GIS, it seems to be a huge learning curve with very little in the line of online tutorials.

Thanks
Jacques